# How to make the vue router link connect to the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am very new to the Vue framework, as well as Javascript, but am currently building a site using Vue and I want to have some links at the top of my site that the user can navigate to. I have tried using the Vue Router (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript) in order to make these links. At this point, I just want to make a little 'About Us' section that the user can navigate to. But, despite the URL changing accordingly to 'localhost:8080/#/about_us', the Vue component that I have associated with the link will not show up.

I have structured my code in the main.js as such:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

export const eventBus = new Vue();
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const AboutUs = {template: '<div>about_us</div>'};

const route = [{path:'/about_us', component: AboutUs}];
const router= new VueRouter({route});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

And then I have my app.vue designed as (note: I reduced much of the code to its essentials for brevity):

```js
import AboutUs from './components/AboutUs.vue'
import { eventBus } from './main.js'

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      films: []
    }
  },
  components: {
  "about-us": AboutUs
  },
  mounted(){
    fetch('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(films => this.films = films)
    .catch(error=> console.log(error))
    }

}
</script>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Ghibli Fandom Extravaganza</h1>
  <nav>
      <li><router-link to="/about_us">About us </router-link></li>
      <router-view></router-view>
  </nav>
  <p>List of Ghibli Movies: <films-list :films="films"/></p>
  <film-detail />
```

At this point, my AboutUs component is only a very basic Vue that shows some information about the site in some simple HTML

tags. But although the link is active and does work, the information from the Vue is not displayed, while the other Vue components continue to show, which indicates that maybe they are not connected? I have tried to follow the tutorial in the Vue Router site, but I don't think that I understand the mechanics of how the code actually works. Can anybody recommend me any corrections?

UPDATE:
Here is the code to my AboutUs.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>This site is for examining the movies of Studio Ghibli</h1>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'about-us'

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: So not sure what the problem is.
`const route = [{path:'/about_us', component: AboutUs}];`

On `/about_us`, you are rendering `AboutUs` component which is a simple div which is About us text. 
I can see that rendering correctly in the snippet you attached.

I know you want to render `films`, but you have not made any routes for `films` component.

Comment: At this point, the films component does not need any routes for it, it will be just on the main site. I can't get the `AboutUs` to render at all.

Comment: Can you add the code for `AboutUs` as well? 
What does it exactly render? 
It renders just the "about_us" text?

Comment: @UtsavPatel check the update on my question

Comment: You don't require to import the aboutUs inside app.vue as it will be rendered in the `<router-view>`

Comment: @bhaskar sadly nothing is being rendered in my `<router-view>`. Not sure what else I need to do to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no  need to import 'aboutus' component. You can just  write like this `<router-link to="about_us">About us </router-link>` 
and in the main.js declare the route like this
`const route = [{path:'/about_us',name:'about_us', component: () => import("path to about us file")}]`;

Comment: I get a `Failed to compile.` error when I set up the route array of object like this above in main.js.

Comment: Update the name attribute as  ```name:'about_us'```.  Previously it was ```name:about_us```

Comment: I updated the code per your suggestion. While it works now and does not fail to compile, I still am unable to get the information from my AboutUs.vue to show at all.

Answer (score 0):

The code samples you provided are a bit confusing, you should simply pass an `imported` view straight in to the `component` property of a `router` entry.

Where you have done:

`const AboutUs = {template: '<div>about_us</div>'};`

Replace that line with:

`import AboutUs from './components/AboutUs.vue'`

I can't figure out from your sample, when and what the relevance of `components: {"about-us": AboutUs },` it is not needed.

Here is a sample of my setup:

**router.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'index',
    component: () => import('../components/views/welcome')
  },
  {
    path: '/about-us',
    name: 'about-us',
    component: () => import('../components/views/about-us')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

export default router
```

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```js
<template>

  <v-app v-cloak>

      <router-link :to="{ name: 'index' }">Welcome</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'about-us' }">About Us</router-link>

      <router-view></router-view>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App'
}

</script>
```

**components/views/about-us.vue**

```js
<template>

  <div>This is the About Us page!</div>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
   name: 'about-us'
  }
</script>
```

This sample uses [History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

**Other things to note**

When routing, `mounted` is unreliable, instead you should place any fetch logic into it's own `method` when calling any :

```js
methods: {
  fetch () {
    // https://github.com/axios/axios
    axios.get('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films').then( ... )
  }
}
```

Call `this.fetch` method in both `beforeRouteUpdate` and `beforeRouteEnter` instead of `mounted`, you can't even rely on `created` when it comes to views handled by `vue-router`.

[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is suggested instead of native [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) because [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) provides more functionality, features and browser compatibility.

In **about-us.vue** you add these [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) like so:

```js
<template>

  <div>This is the About Us page!</div>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
   name: 'about-us'

  methods: {
    fetch () {
      axios.get('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films').then( ... )
    }
  }

  // Will fire if you are already on the view but a parameter changes (dynamic routing)
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
     this.fetch()
     next()
  },

  // Will fire when you enter the view
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    this.fetch()
    next()
  },

}
</script>
```

> Both should be added, understand that they won't fire at the same time, only one of them will execute `fetch` once when relevant.

This will resolve any issues you would otherwise encounter with [Dynamic Routing](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) should you ever use them.

**Folder Structure**

```
 src/
 + App.vue
 + main.js
 + router.js
 + vue.config.js
 + assets/
    + logo.png
 + components/
    + views/
       + welcome.vue
       + about-us.vue
```

Hope this clears up the setup requirement for you.

Comment: I followed your lead and replaced `const AboutUs = {template: '<div>about_us</div>'};` with `import AboutUs from './components/AboutUs.vue'`, but I still have no luck getting my AboutUs to render. Please check my question's update above to see how I structured it (it's quite simple to be honest). I will try to reconfigure my code to your suggestion by putting the router as another file. But what does `mode: history` do in the Vue object?

Comment: History mode will get rid of anchor link style urls. `localhost:8080/#/about-us` will become `localhost:8080/about-us` and browser back/forward navigation will work.
The code I supplies is 95% a direct copy from my own project, should work for you.

Comment: Hey, I have tried to replicate your code structure as closely as possible in my project, but sadly I have had no luck in getting the information from my AboutUs.vue to display. I have checked this quite closely and the major difference I encountered was the file path to your AboutUs.vue, which was `'../components/views/about-us'`. I do not have a Views folder, and am now wondering if there is some kind of structural part I am missing from my project in order to have my AboutUs Vue get rendered properly. But thanks for your comprehensive response, I apologize again but I am very new to this.

Comment: Well yes, of course you will have to adapt any paths to files in the example to reflect where things actually are in your own project, everybody's folder structure preference is different. I would recommend you put "views" in a `view` folder to keep them separate from independent components.

Comment: I just noticed in your original post you use javascripts `fetch` method for getting data.
Many developers import and use `axios` https://github.com/axios/axios